# search and append a string inside a configuration file

Tags: unix, search, awk, sed, append

i have a folder that contain more than 200 folder every folder has a file named default.conf. the issue is i want search and append inside all default.conf files this : $site/
for example i have :

/var/rSave/$site/default.conf

and all default.conf their is a line contain : root_path    /var/rSave/
so i want to change all lines in default.conf files to the next :

root_path    /var/rsave/sitename.com/

that's why i try to execute the  next shell :

```
for site in $(ls /var/rSave/); do   
sed -i "s/ snapshot_root   \/var\/rSave\/ / snapshot_root   \/var\/rSave\/$site\/ /g" /var/rSave/$site/default.conf ;
done
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typed snapshot_root instead of root_path

```
for site in $(ls /var/rSave/); do   
   sed -i "s/root_path \/var\/rSave\//root_path \/var\/rSave\/$site\/ /g" /var/rSave/$site/default.conf ;
done
```

Comment: i want add at the end of line : $site/